# Kendo grid sortingI

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the codes below for example:

```
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: students,
                pageable: false
            },
            scrollable: true
            sortable: true,
            selectable: true,
            columns: [
                { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: 230},
                { field: "Sex", title: "Sex", width: 50 },
                { field: "Ca", title: "C.A." , width: 55 },
                { field: "TotolScore", title: "Totol Score", width: 100 },
                { field: "Rank", title: "Rank", width: 60 }
            ]
        });
```

---

The codes above allows me to do sorting of columns.  But I need to do extra special for the "Rank" column.  What I want is when I click the column "Rank" it will sort but based on "TotalScore" value.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

When a column is sortable, you can define a `compare` function and this does not have to compare the same column.

Example: Replace your `Rank` column definition by this...

```
    { 
        field: "Rank", 
        title: "Rank",
        width: 60,
        sortable : {
            compare : function (a, b) {
                return a.TotolScore - b.TotolScore;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, I define a column that will show the value of `Rank` but I define my own `compare` function that is actually working on `TotalScore` values.

You can check [`compare`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.sortable.compare) documentation for more information.

And check a running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/p2tsupvx/